# byte[] to strongly typed array?

Tags: c#, serialization, byte

I having some issues with converting a large byte[] array into a strongly typed array.

1. I have an array which has been concatinated into one large byte[] array and stored in a table.
2. I want to then read this byte[] array but convert it to a strongly typed array.

As I have stored the entire array as a byte[] array, can I not read that byte array and convert it to my strongly typed version? ***At the moment its returning null...***

Is this possible in one hit?

Thanks in advance, Onam.

```
<code>
    #region Save
    public void Save<T>(T[] Array) where T : new()
    {
        List<byte[]> _ByteCollection = new List<byte[]>();
        byte[] _Bytes = null;
        int _Length = 0;
        int _Offset = 0;

        foreach (T _Item in Array)
        {
            _ByteCollection.Add(Serialise(_Item));
        }
        foreach (byte[] _Byte in _ByteCollection)
        {
            _Length += _Byte.Length;
        }

        _Bytes = new byte[_Length];

        foreach (byte[] b in _ByteCollection)
        {
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, _Bytes, _Offset, b.Length);
            _Offset += b.Length;
        }
        Customer[] c = BinaryDeserialize<Customer[]>(_Bytes);
    }
    #endregion

    #region BinaryDeserialize
    public static T BinaryDeserialize<T>(byte[] RawData)
    {
        T _DeserializedContent = default(T);

        BinaryFormatter _Formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream _Stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                _Stream.Write(RawData, 0, RawData.Length);
                _Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                _DeserializedContent = (T)_Formatter.Deserialize(_Stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _DeserializedContent = default(T);
        }

        return _DeserializedContent;
    }
    #endregion
</code>
```

Comment: What do you see happening in the debugger?

Comment: a byte[] is a strongly typed array (it's type as an array of bytes)

Comment: My save method is looping through an array of Customer and copying each Customer (represented as byte[]) to another array (representing an array of them). I am the passing that SAME giant array of byte[] to Deserialize method. I am hoping here to deserialize to array of Customer[]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are serializing each item to a list, then concatenating the bytes. When this is deserialised this just looks like the data for one customer plus some unexpected data (the other customers) at the end.

I don't know how your serialize method works but you can probably just change code:

```
    foreach (T _Item in Array)
    {
        _ByteCollection.Add(Serialise(_Item));
    }
```

To:

```
_ByteCollection.Add(Serialise(Array));
```

And that should work, then you could probably simplify it a little.

Comment: Jesus christ ARGH!!!! ARGH!!! ARGH!!! ARGH ARGH ARGH ARGH ARGH!!! YES!!! That has sorted it! Can't believe it was because of that ARGH!!!! :'( Thank you very much for that, can't believe it. I've been staring at it for so long my brain has officially turned into jelly!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the line

```
_DeserializedContent = (T)_Formatter.Deserialize(_Stream);
```

throws an exception. In the catch block you simply swallow and ignore that exception.

Comment: Yeah that is returning null, however I am using the same byte[] array that was generated from the Save method to deserialize...